# Angular 6 Basic Auth Post Request to .NET Core API

Tags: angular, api, post, .net-core, angular6

This problem has been posted a bunch of times, but I tried several of the solutions and they are not working for me. I'm making an API service in angular that needs to use basic authentication to get a bearer token to use for other endpoints. The API is written in .NET Core.

My code is simple:

```
private GetToken() {
    let delta = new Date().getTime() - this.tokenTimestamp.getTime();

    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.user + ':' + this.pass)
        })
    };

    console.log(options);

    if (delta >= 60000) {
        this.http.post<Response>(this.url + '/api/Auth/Token/', { username: this.user, password: this.pass }, options)
        .subscribe(
        (val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
        },
        response => {
            console.log("POST call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        });
    }
}
```

I get CORS errors (I think) in my console: 
[image]

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: CORS should be dealt with on the server not the client. There is nothing you can do there, you need to update your API to send a `access-control-allow-origin` header

Comment: I'm testing from Postman and SQL Server and the POST is going through fine... I think it's something I'm doing wrong in Angular (client side).

Comment: postman and sql server do not use client JS to send the request, that's the issue with CORS.. and that's what all the answers on this site tell you to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it looks like there is a CORS issue, which may or may not really exist, first you need to resolve your 404 Not Found error. In our apps as well, when there is a 404 Not Found, the 404 error is usually tailed with a CORS error even though the CORS config is perfectly set up.

To test this, open Postman. Create a POST request to your localhost:50897/api/Auth/Token/ and see if you are still getting a 404. If yes, you would be looking at making sure that your endpoint is good.

**edit:**

In your Startup.cs, make sure you have this in Configure(..) { }

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "url2") // url2 would be the IP address that your angular app is deployed under in IIS
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod());
```

Comment: Thanks @dexter -- it's working perfectly in Postman. I made sure of that before posting here.

Comment: @brandoncluff In that case, please show what your Configure() in Startup.cs looks like or see the edit.

Comment: Ding ding ding! This fixed my problem. I'm testing on localhost for the .NETCore API and the Angular6 app... When I deploy, will I still need this app.UseCors builder?